# Use SnackBar with CupertinoPageScaffold

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-cupertino

Is there a way to use a `SnackBar` with a `CupertinoPageScaffold`?

I am getting the following error:

```
Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.
No Scaffold ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to Scaffold.of().
```

Invoking a `SnackBar` in a child widget using:

```
final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'),
      action: SnackBarAction(
      label: 'Undo',
      onPressed: () {
      // Some code to undo the change!
      },
      ),
      );

// Find the Scaffold in the Widget tree and use it to show a SnackBar!
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

Comment: where are you calling the `showSnackBar` inside your code hierarchy ?

Comment: @MazinIbrahim because I am invoking it `onTap` as shown in Flutter's example,  https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/snackbars#1-create-a-scaffold

Comment: Did you try the complete example at the end of the page https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/snackbars#1-create-a-scaffold

Comment: @MazinIbrahim yep, but I'm using a `CupertinoPageScaffold` instead of a material `Scaffold`

Answer (score 4):

You need to include a `Scaffold` as `CupertinoPageScaffold` isn't a child of it, then you need to separate the code where you call the `showSnackBar` function from that of `Scaffold` into a separate class which is here the `SnackBarBody` because a `SnackBar` and a `Scaffold` can't be called from the same `Build` function. Here's a complete working example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() => runApp(SnackBarDemo());

class SnackBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
     title: 'SnackBar Demo',
     home: CupertinoPageScaffold(
    child: SnackBarPage(),
       ),
     );
   }
 }

class SnackBarPage extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
   body: SnackBarBody(),
   );
 }
}

class SnackBarBody extends StatefulWidget {
  SnackBarBody({Key key,}):
      super(key: key);

  @override
  _SnackBarBodyState createState() => new _SnackBarBodyState();
}

class _SnackBarBodyState extends State<SnackBarBody> {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Center(
    child: RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'),action: SnackBarAction(label: 'Undo',
          onPressed: () {
            // Some code to undo the change!
          },
        ),
      );

        // Find the Scaffold in the Widget tree and use it to show a SnackBar!
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
       },
      child: Text('Show SnackBar'),
     ),
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is the ideal solution. Flutter recommends against nesting `Scaffold`s as it can cause unintended behaviors. Seems like I cannot use a snackbar if I am using a `Cupertino` based app.

Comment: I agree with you Alan. If you badly need a `Scaffold` I think it is the only available method.

Answer (score 2):

Cupertino widgets should be specific for iOS, `SnackBar` come to replace Android `Toasts` but there is no Android `Toast` equivalent in iOS, so you cannot natively add a `SnackBar` to a `CupertinoScaffold` as it will not follow iOS guidelines.

One solution will be to extend `CupertinoScaffold` and add it the `SnackBar` code.

An other is in Mazin Ibrahim [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55383943/10286880), note that it isn't recommended to nest Scaffolds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Definitely looking to avoid nesting scaffolds. Is extending a Flutter widget a common pattern? What's the most common approach for showing snackbar-like or toast-like messages on iOS via the `CupertinoPageScaffold`? Or is `CupertinoPageScaffold` just not really suited for timed messages, and just use `Scaffold`? Trying to learn and integrate Cupertino with Material, but various aspects seem a bit restrictive.

Comment: Yes, Flutter widgets doesn't give what you want extending it is a great idea. I don't really use much Cupertino Widgets so I don't know what is the common behavior for this, maybe using `CupertinoAlertDiaolg` with a timer to make them diseapear? But this will freeze the ui... I think using `Scaffold` is your best possible approch if you don't want to take a lot of time for this. `Scaffold` isn't a lot different from a `CupertinoScaffold` and I don't think you will have trouble to make `Scaffold` look like a `CupertinoScaffold`

Answer (score 2):

Although, it is not possible to use [`showSnackBar`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldMessengerState/showSnackBar.html) with `CupertinoPageScaffold`, but you can create customisable SnackBar like feature for iOS (CupertinoPageScaffold) by making use of [`OverlayEntry`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/OverlayEntry-class.html).

> Because an [`Overlay`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html) uses a [`Stack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) layout, overlay entries can use [`Positioned`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) and [`AnimatedPositioned`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedPositioned-class.html) to position themselves within the overlay.

Here, I've created a function `showCupertinoSnackBar` for easier use:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void showCupertinoSnackBar({
  required BuildContext context,
  required String message,
  int durationMillis = 3000,
}) {
  final overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
    builder: (context) => Positioned(
      bottom: 8.0,
      left: 8.0,
      right: 8.0,
      child: CupertinoPopupSurface(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 8.0,
            vertical: 8.0,
          ),
          child: Text(
            widget.message,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14.0,
              color: CupertinoColors.secondaryLabel,
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  Future.delayed(
    Duration(milliseconds: durationMillis),
    overlayEntry.remove,
  );
  Overlay.of(Navigator.of(context).context)?.insert(overlayEntry);
}
```

You can customise the SnackBar to your liking. If you need to animate the overlay, here's another example using `AnimatedPositioned` inside a stateful widget:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void showCupertinoSnackBar({
  required BuildContext context,
  required String message,
  int durationMillis = 3000,
}) {
  const animationDurationMillis = 200;
  final overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
    builder: (context) => _CupertinoSnackBar(
      message: message,
      animationDurationMillis: animationDurationMillis,
      waitDurationMillis: durationMillis,
    ),
  );
  Future.delayed(
    Duration(milliseconds: durationMillis + 2 * animationDurationMillis),
    overlayEntry.remove,
  );
  Overlay.of(Navigator.of(context).context)?.insert(overlayEntry);
}

class _CupertinoSnackBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final String message;
  final int animationDurationMillis;
  final int waitDurationMillis;

  const _CupertinoSnackBar({
    Key? key,
    required this.message,
    required this.animationDurationMillis,
    required this.waitDurationMillis,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<_CupertinoSnackBar> createState() => _CupertinoSnackBarState();
}

class _CupertinoSnackBarState extends State<_CupertinoSnackBar> {
  bool _show = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.microtask(() => setState(() => _show = true));
    Future.delayed(
      Duration(
        milliseconds: widget.waitDurationMillis,
      ),
      () {
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() => _show = false);
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedPositioned(
      bottom: _show ? 8.0 : -50.0,
      left: 8.0,
      right: 8.0,
      curve: _show ? Curves.linearToEaseOut : Curves.easeInToLinear,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: widget.animationDurationMillis),
      child: CupertinoPopupSurface(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 8.0,
            vertical: 8.0,
          ),
          child: Text(
            widget.message,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14.0,
              color: CupertinoColors.secondaryLabel,
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was surprised that its so difficult to use a snackbar when using Cupertino widgets. I get that its not native to iOS, but it certainly wouldn't hurt to have an easier platform independent snackbar solution in the Flutter SDK.

Comment: The Only Correction in the Above solution is  
- in showCupertinoSnackBar , 
-- Replace Overlay.of(Navigator.of(context).context)?.insert(overlayEntry) 
-- to Overlay.of(context).insert(overlayEntry)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `SnackBar` inside `CupertinoApp`, just wrap your `CupertinoApp` by `ScaffoldMessenger`:

```dart
ScaffoldMessenger(
   child: CupertinoApp(
     ...
   )
)
```

Here working full example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// this is working code, just copy and create 'main_test.dart' in your lib folder
// and then press play button near main function (AndroidStudio)
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const ScaffoldMessenger( // just add this (MaterialApp has ScaffoldMessenger inside but CupertinoApp does not)
      child: CupertinoApp(
        title: 'Snackbars inside CupertinoApp Demo',
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print('Show snack bar pressed');
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
              content: Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'),
              // your need add some customization for snackbar, because it has white text on white background
              // but you can create own customized Theme which provides styles for snackbars and also put it
              // in widgets tree upper
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            ));
          },
          child: const Text('Show snack bar'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```